# Problems creating desktop shortcut to Tkinter script

Tags: python

I want to develop an app using Tkinter GUI and want to launch it from a Desktop icon.
I have created the script which works from the terminal and from IDLE3 and is just a test script at present.I have made this executable with `chmod +x`
I have made a .desktop file and put it in `/usr/share/applications/`
I have not made any specific permission changes to this file.
I have also put it in the `/home/pi/Desktop/`
I have an icon on the desktop and an entry under Other in the menu.
I am getting the error:

```
invalid desktop entry file: '/home/pi/Desktop/Gort.desktop'
```

from clicking on the icon and similar from the menu entry:

```
invalid desktop entry file: '/usr/share/applications/Gort.desktop'
```

This is my desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Name=Gort
   Comment= Gort Pi Status Info
   Exec=/usr/bin/python/home/pi/Gort/py
   Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/Sqeak.png
   Terminal=false
   Type=Applications
   Categories=None
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `chmod 777 ~/Desktop/Gort.desktop` and then tried running it to make sure this is a permissions problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the errors.

I modified this line

```
Exec=/usr/bin/python/home/pi/Gort/py
```

to

```
Exec=/home/pi/Gort.py #location of the file
```

And in the file Gort.py I modified the shebang from

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3 #the script is python3
```